# How to get the value of the date input in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, datepicker, date-format

I have a Signup form that takes a date as input.

The code of my date input is:

```
birthDate: new Date(),

this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
this.handledChange = this.handledChange.bind(this);


handledChange(date) {
  this.setState({
    birthDate: date
  });
}

<ControlLabel>Date de naissance</ControlLabel>
  <FormGroup controlId="birthDate" bsSize="large">
    <FormControl
      autoFocus
      type="date"
      value={this.state.birthDate}
      onChange={this.handledChange}
    />
  </FormGroup>
```

When I submit it, the input date is `undefined` on the console.

I want it in the format : `YYYY-MM-DD`

How can I fix that please?

Answer (score 4):

You won't get selected date directly it should be through event target

Change

```
handledChange(date) {
    this.setState({
      birthDate: date
    });
  }
```

To

```
handledChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      birthDate: event.target.value
    });
  }
```

Comment: It is still the same issue, it is `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

You can also extract the input value of your form using its Id, after submission.
You can try using like this in your submit method:

**let selectedDate = document.getElementById('birthDate')**

BirthDate here refers to controlId of FormGroup

Comment: it is the same issue

Comment: Just a small question that I can think of from the top of my head. Did you make sure whether your submit handler is being called upon submission?

Answer (score 1):

This works like a gem. please try it out if you are still facing the issue

```
             <input
                type="date"
                name="expiration date"
                value={this.state.expiration_date}
                onChange={event => this.setState({expiration_date: event.target.value})} 
              />
```

```
onChange = (key, value) => {
    this.setState({
      [key]: value
    })
  }
```

Comment: What are the advantages of this over the accepted answer? When adding answers to older questions with accepted answers it is really important to point out what new aspect of the question your answer addresses. Code only answers can almost always be improved by the addition of some explanation of how and why they work.

Comment: @JasonAller what accepted answer? There's no accepted answer at all and OP says those answers are not working for him. In fact, Aravind's way is the correct way.